# How to add html icon in FPDF for php?

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

I have trying to add html icon in FPDF. I have tried the following:

```
$pdf->WriteHTML('You can<br><span style="font-size:24px" class="fa fa-map-marker"></span><br><p align="center">center a line</p><br><hr>');
```

However, when I try to run it, I am getting Output with out icon only text :

```
Name: name Email: email URl: url Comment: comment
```